# How can I do Facebook video calls?

Tags: facebook

My question is how I can do video calls on Facebook, I'm new to Linux, recently installed Ubuntu 11.10. I really like the OS but I can not make video calls on Facebook and this is terrible. Please anyone who can help in this.

Comment: Aren't Facebook video calls available only on Windows?.

Comment: "This is terrible" Let's be positive.

Comment: you will have to try to use skybe coz video call is not supported yet in facebook and i had the same issue

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, Facebook does not support video calling on Ubuntu yet, as explained on the [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=177940565599960). They haven't developed their plugin yet.

However, video calling (popularly known as *Hangouts*) works on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/), for example (after installing a plugin). If you are curious in upcoming technologies, you also can take a look at [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/demo).

Comment: what if we install windows mozilla firefox on ubuntu through wine?? am not sure what I am saying but it does makes sense. I think..

Answer (score 5):

### **14.04+**

Full support now (January 2015). You no longer need to install a special plugin or anything. You only need a supported browser which is firefox or chrome/chromium etc.

Opera is mentioned but I would be surprised if anything other than the Opera developer version for linux was supported because linux opera is severely outdated but who knows, all I know is that it works fine and tested less than 10 minutes ago on firefox-34.0 with nothing to install.

To start a video call:

1. Open a chat window with a friend
2. Click [image] in the top right corner

If your friend isn't currently able to receive a video call the will be grayed out, and you'll see a message that says "[Name] is currently unavailable for video calling."

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not currently support Linux. If you were to go to someone's profile, you would only see 'message' and settings. We can only wait for Facebook to accept Linux.
As Agmenor mentioned, video calls are available for [Google+](http://plus.google.com) and also for [Skype](http://www.skype.com)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Facebook video call on Ubuntu for now.

> Video calling is **not** currently available on Linux.

Source: [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/211644178877843)