# How  to make a video call using Facebook?

Tags: video, webcam, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do Facebook video calls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96668/how-can-i-do-facebook-video-calls)

I need to make a video call using Facebook, but I can't. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that video from Facebook works. It is only Skype. Why can't you use Skype for Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately video calls in FB are still not supported as they have plugins for Mac/Windows only:

[image]

If you an option to switch to a different hosting service you can use Skype or Google+.