# Can you help me with Facebook videocall?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do Facebook video calls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96668/how-can-i-do-facebook-video-calls)

I am unable to a videocall in facebook. is there any plug-in, which can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Unfortunately Facebook currently provide plugin only for Windows and Mac OS.